# After transition is complete, show the div

Tags: html, css

Dear Stackoverflow readers,

Using only CSS3, how do I show a div after a transition is completed.

This is the snippet of HTML I'm working with

```
<div class="biography">
      <p>Title</p>
      <p id="moreBio">This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.</p>
</div>
```

This is the snippet of CSS3 I'm working with

```
.biography {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #3399FF;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    right: 5%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.biography:hover {
    width: 200px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 10px 10px 0px -100px;
    opacity: 1;
    background: #7C7C7C;
}
#moreBio {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
#moreBio:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I want #moreBio to show after the transition is completed, how would I go about doing that?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `transition-delay` to `#moreBio` equal to the transition time of `.biography`, and make the appearance trigger when `.biography` is hovered upon.

```
#moreBio {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease;
}
.biography:hover  #moreBio {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, can you explain the logic behind ".biography:hover #moreBio" vs. just "#moreBio"?  Is it because when the mouse hovers over.biography that is when the CSS applies to #moreBio?

Comment: @Tony You got it. If you vocalize it to yourself, that's what you want: "when the user hovers over .biography, then I want #moreBio to have the following styles..."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `#moreBio:hover` you could do `.biography:hover #moreBio` and then add a delay for the `#moreBio` transition like so

```
// ... other code just like it's

#moreBio {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
     -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.biography:hover #moreBio {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is the [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/R9PUQ/).

Comment: Thank you for showing a working sample. 

If you don't mind me asking another question, is there any way for me to make #moreBio opacity transition back to 0 faster when the mouse is no longer hovering?  Would using :after work?  Or am I misunderstanding the use of :after?

Comment: `:after` is used to add some content to the element so it's not the solution to your problem. The solution is to apply transition and delay only when the parent element (`.biography` is your case) is hovered. Here is the updated sample : http://jsfiddle.net/R9PUQ/1/